# Не меняет state

Tags: reactjs

подскажите пожалуйста в чем дело?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Старайтесь предоставить пример кода в виде текста, а не картинки. Вам быстрее помогут и не будут минусовать пост почём зря.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchJokes`  работает асинхронно и массив jokes1 формируется уже после того как вызван метод `setState()`.

Вот так будет работать:

```js
async pushState() {
  let jokes1 = [];
  for(...) {
    const joke = await this.fetchJokes();
    jokes1.push(...);
  }
  ...
}
```

То что вы видите корректный результат отработки первого консоль лога - это побочный эффект работы со ссылками в JS: console.log не копирует массив перед выводом, а просто выводит то что есть и потом обновляет результат вывод до того состояния которое получилось.

Для проверки можете сделать `console.log([...jokes1])`. Тогда выведется изначальный массив на момент выполнения `console.log` и результат вывода не будет обновляться. Вывод `console.log` будет пустым массивом.

Comment: Про console.log не знал, спасибо огромное!